# Can an awaited Task return false in IsCompleted

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I found this piece of code:

```
Task task = DoSomethingAsync( someObject );
await task.ConfigureAwait( false );
if ( task.IsCompleted ){ ... }
```

I wonder if I can safely replace it with

```
await DoSomethingAsync( someObject ).ConfigureAwait( false );
```

and drop the if clause.

My question: can `task.IsCompleted` ever be false when an awaited task has returned?

The [documentation of IsCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompleted?view=net-5.0)  tells us:

> `true` if the task has completed (that is, the task is in one of the three final states: RanToCompletion, Faulted, or Canceled); otherwise, `false`.

I looked up the possible [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus?view=net-5.0#fields) but it is still not clear to me which of the states is possible when the awaited task hast returned.

Please help me to shed light on this matter. Thanx in advace.

Comment: Completed is completed

Comment: When an awaited task has returned, then that means that `The task completed execution successfully.` which is the description of the `RanToCompletion` state

Comment: What were you going to do if the task wasn't completed after the await? Loop back and await some more?

Comment: @RaymondChen that is a very good question. The code lacks an elsen case. So I would never get to know ;)

Comment: [Many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582186/canceled-task-also-appears-as-completed) [people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61447147) have fallen into the trap to believe that `IsCompleted` means `IsCompletedSuccessfully`, and whoever wrote your code was probably one of them. The culprit is probably Microsoft, because the [`IsCompletedSuccessfully`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompletedsuccessfully) property did not exist from the beginning, when the `Task` type was introduced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Docs: await operator (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await)

> The await operator suspends evaluation of the enclosing async method until the asynchronous operation represented by its operand completes.

After `Task taskInstance = ...; await taskInstance;`, `taskInstance.IsCompleted` will always be true.

Comment: your answer implies that the task has returned it cannot be in any of the remaining states but "RanToCompletion, Faulted, or Canceled" as stated in the documentation. This is  a point that I could not find in the documentation and was unsure about

Comment: @Mong note that the C# reference isn't proper documentation as well, it's a "getting started guide". I think this could be clarified in the proper docs, I couldn't find it there either.

Comment: thank you for the answer and the effort. "in the proper docs, I couldn't find it there either. " I probably would need to read the `Task` code in the end.... if I shall mess up something badly changing the existing code ;) cheers

Answer (score 0):

Based on this article:
https://profinit.eu/en/blog/lets-dive-into-async-await-in-c-part-3/
the example that you found is a bad approach. So you can use safely the version:

```
await DoSomethingAsync( someObject ).ConfigureAwait( false );
```

You can omit `ConfigureAwait(false)` but depends on the context where you use the method `DoSomethingAsync`.